# Include resources from *.pri file

Tags: c++, qt, qmake

I have some problems with including resources from a *.pri file in Qt. Basically my test.pri file looks like this:

```
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD
SOURCES     += $$PWD/testdlg.cpp
HEADERS     += $$PWD/testdlg.h 
FORMS       += $$PWD/testdlg.ui 
RESOURCES   += $$PWD/res.qrc
```

The *.ico files are stored in a sub folder $$PWD/res and I added them succesfully to my res.qrc file, which looks like this:

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/">
        <file>res/Icon1.ico</file>
        <file>res/Icon2.ico</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

I include that test.pri file to my *.pro file:

```
include(Tests/test.pri)
```

In Qt Designer I can see all the icons when I open my test.ui file. I can chose the icon of a QToolButton (for example) from resource via the property manager of the Designer. Everything works as expected. However, when I compile the applcation, the icons are not displayed.

If I do not use a *.pri file, the icons for the QToolButton are displayed.
Can anyone give me a hint what I am missing here?

Comment: How do you compile your application? From Qt creator? Are you getting any warnings when you run it?

Comment: I compile from Qt creator with MSVC2013 compiler. It doesnt give me any warnings or errors.

Comment: If it matter: I use Qt creator 3.5.0 and Qt 5.5.0 MSVC 2013, 32 bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't get what was wrong. After spending yesterday's evening with analysing the problem without any success, I opened Qt creator this morning and everything works fine. Maybe I just had to restart Qt creator after adding the resources? I cannot tell.

Answer (score 0):

Let's call your main project file `main.pro`. Then from your provided information, I assume you have

```
/main.pro
/Tests/test.pri
```

Since `$$PWD` is the .pri file's parent, I assume you have

```
/main.pro
/Tests/test.pri
/Tests/testdlg.cpp
/Tests/testdlg.h
/Tests/testdlg.ui
/Tests/res.qrc
```

Now the entries in the qrc file are relative to its parent dir, so you have:

```
/main.pro
/Tests/test.pri
/Tests/testdlg.cpp
/Tests/testdlg.h
/Tests/testdlg.ui
/Tests/res.qrc
/Tests/res/Icon1.ico
/Tests/res/Icon2.ico
```

From your qrc prefix, I assume you call the resources via

```
qrc:/res/Icon1.ico
qrc:/res/Icon2.ico
```

Are those assumptions all correct?

Comment: Yes, that is how my project is structured!